# Javascript toggle isnt working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

I have the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle('husob_filter_orderby')" value=""/><?php echo JTEXT::_('FILTER_TH_ORDERBY'); ?></input><br>

<div id="husob_filter_orderby" style="display: none;">
    <select name="orderby" class="select">
        <option value="datetime_asc" ><?php echo JTEXT::_('FILTER_ORDER_DTASC'); ?></option>;
        <option value="datetime_desc"><?php echo JTEXT::_('FILTER_ORDER_DTDES'); ?></option>;
        <option value="ofiden_asc"><?php echo JTEXT::_('FILTER_ORDER_DENASC'); ?></option>;
        <option value="ofiden_desc"><?php echo JTEXT::_('FILTER_ORDER_DENDES'); ?></option>;
    </select>
</div>
```

The toggle inside the `input` isnt functioning correctly. When I click the button it just hides the checkbox and doesnt toggle the `div`.

What is wrong?

**EDIT:** The toggle function is being called inside an imported file and not very sure where I can locate it. I know the code works because it works on another version of Joomla but not on a newer version.

**EDIT 2:** I get no javascript errors.

Comment: show your `toggle()` function

Comment: `toggle` isn't a built-in function. If you didn't write it or aren't using a library that created it, then it won't exist. Check your javascript log, you should have an error saying that the function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know what you mean by `toggle()`  and `toggle` isn't a built-in function but you can also use this for toggle

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="$('#husob_filter_orderby').toggle();" value=""/>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, how simple could that be! Thanks!